# Usage of if NOT statement

Tags: javascript

```
    function statsForDays(data) {
    var days = {};
    var currentDate;
    var lastValue;

    for (var i=0, l=data.length; i<l; i++) {
        var element = data[i];
        var timestamp = element[0];
        var value = element[1];
        var date = new Date(timestamp);
        if (!lastValue) lastValue = value;
        if (currentDate != date.getDate()) {
            currentDate = date.getDate();
            days[String(date.getMonth()+1)+'-'+String(currentDate)] = value - lastValue;

            lastValue = value;
        }
    }

    return days;
}
```

Can anyone explain to me how does the above function works? I know how it results, but would like to know what does `if (!lastValue) lastValue = value;`do in the function? It seems a kind of algorithm, but how does it works? as `lastvalue` was set equal to the `value` why to subtruct them from each other later in `days[String(date.getMonth()+1)+'-'+String(currentDate)] = value - lastValue;`? and why then equal them again?

Comment: @freefaller This question is **on-topic here** per [help/on-topic], and off-topic on programmers. Please don't recommend sites if you don't understand their scope: [**What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow**](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7182/what-goes-on-programmers-se-a-guide-for-stack-overflow)

Comment: Apologies @durron597

Comment: `!lastValue` would be true if the value of lastValue is undefined, null, "" (empty string), false, NaN or 0, as the boolean representation for each one eval as `false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When loop begins iterating it checks whether variable is equal to some value or not? if `lastvalue` is set to nothing the it equals `lastvalue` to `value` or if `lastvalue` has some value then the first `if` statement does not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Each iteration of the loop is recording the difference of days between each row of data. However for index 0 there is no "previous" element to compare to. When it says "if (!lastValue)" that means, "if last value equals 0". Then it will subtract value-value and record a 0 for that difference in days.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `lastValue` begins unitialised, and will by default equal `undefined`. If `lastValue` remained undefined, the first element of the output `days` would have value `NaN` because the output of `(value - undefined)` would inevitably be incalculable.

This function seems to return each "M-D" along with the value minus the previous day's value. Repeat days are disregarded:

```
statsForDays([ 
  [new Date(2015,0,1),3], 
  [new Date(2015,1,2), 4], 
  [new Date(2015,2,3), 11], 
  [new Date(2015,3,5), 5], 
  [new Date(2015,3,5), 5] ]
            )

/*
Returns:
Object { 1-1=0,  2-2=1,  3-3=7, 4-5=-6 }
*/
```